# Using an event listener inside a class method to call another class method returning undefined

Tags: es6-class

I'm just learning how to use javascript classes. I'm having some difficulty understanding how to make event listeners call methods within a class. Specifically, whenever I call the **this.infoBoxActive** on click, all my variables in the method return undefined.

What I eventually want to do is have a toggle method that onclick switches between true and false and then calls either infoBoxActive or infoBoxDective based on its state. I've been playing around with my code most of the day trying various things but I seem to be sparking the same issue of my variables going undefined. If I call the method direct my everything works great.

I've been using a promise to gather my data from a local JSON file, but I wasn't sure how to return the Object in my resolve so right now I'm calling all my new classes from the promise. I don't know if this would be part of the problem.

I've tried reading some posts of similarity, but either I wasn't able to understand the solution or it wasn't pertaining to my exact problem, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

```
class EpisodeInfoBox extends Episode {
  constructor({ title, date, description, tracklist } = {}) {
    super({ title, date, description, tracklist })

    this.titleContainer = document.querySelector('.episode-title');
    this.dateContainer = document.querySelector('.episode-date');
    this.descriptionContainer = document.querySelector('.episode-description');
    this.tracklistContainer = document.querySelector('.episode-tracklist');

    this.infoBoxButton = document.getElementById('infoBoxButton');

    this.infoBoxButton.addEventListener('click', this.infoBoxActive);
  }



  infoBoxActive(){
    this.titleContainer.innerHTML = this.title;
    this.dateContainer.innerHTMLs = this.date;
    this.descriptionContainer.innerHTML = this.description;

    // Creates list-items for track list
    let tracklistHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tracklist.length; i++) {
      tracklistHTML += `<li>${this.tracklist[i].song} - ${this.tracklist[i].artist}</li>`;
    }
    this.tracklistContainer.innerHTML = tracklistHTML;
  }
}
```

my promise

```
export default function service(url) {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    xhr.onerror = function(error) {
      rej(error)
    }
    xhr.send();

    function handleResponse() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          var resObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          res(resObject)
        } else {
          rej(this.statusText)
        }
      }
    };
  });
}
```

My resolve

```
function callService(){
  service('/data/episodes.json')
    .then(retrieveEpisode)
    .then(makeEpisode)
    .catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e)
    });
}

function retrieveEpisode(episodeArray) {
  return episodeArray[0];

}

function makeEpisode(episode){
  let newEpisode = new Episode(episode);
    newEpisode.setEpisodeImage();
  let newAudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(episode);
  let newEpisodeInfoBox = new EpisodeInfoBox(episode);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
 this.infoBoxButton.addEventListener('click', this.infoBoxActive);
```

to this:

```
this.infoBoxButton.addEventListener('click', this.infoBoxActive.bind(this));
```

When an event listener is called, it will not have your object's `this` pointer set so `infoBoxActive()` is called with an inappropriate value of `this` and thus you don't see the properties you expect.  You can use `.bind()` as shown above to reattach the appropriate `this` value before calling your method.

---

In Javascript, when you pass `this.infoBoxActive` as an argument to a function, a reference to the `.infoBoxActive` method is passed, but there is no connection at all to `this`.  It's just a reference to a function.  So, the listener then calls that function and sets its own value for `this` which will not be your object.  Using `.bind()` you can create a function stub that will set the value of `this` for you when calling your function.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks so much! Can't tell you how much I've been editing my code to work around this. Your explanation was great too. If you have a second would you mind if I ask you this second question? Right now I'm implementing all my class creation and functions in my service promise because I couldn't figure out how to get the object array outside of the promise. I have a really strong suspicion this is a bad idea. You don't have to tell me how to correct it just let me know if it is a bad practice ;)

Comment: @Jleibham - I don't understand your other question.  If you want help with that, I'd suggest you post a new question, show the relevant code and ask a specific question about that code.